# Jquery form submission not working by using right syntax

Tags: jquery, jscript

While giving input type button giving action absolutely correct and submitting the form by jquery or jscript, my form is not submitting. Is there any way to solve this problem?

my code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".sumbitbtn").click(function(e) {

    var regEmail = new RegExp(/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/);
    var selection       = document.myfrm.user_type;
    var lawfirm_name    =   $('#lawfirm_name').val();
    var first_name      =   $('#first_name').val();
    var last_name       =   $('#last_name').val();
    var mobile_no       =   $('#mobile_no').val();
    var email_id        =   $('#email_id').val();
    var practice_area   =   $('#practice_area').val();
    var cvalue          =   $('#authentication').val();


    var arr_msg         = Array();
    var count           = arr_msg.length;
    var alreadyFocussed = false;
    //alert(time1);
    //alert(start_date);
    if(selection[1].checked == true)
    {
    if(lawfirm_name=='')
    {
        $("#error_lawfirm_name").html('Please enter Lawfirm Name!');

        if(!alreadyFocussed){
            $('#lawfirm_name').focus();
            alreadyFocussed = true;
        }
        count++;
    }else{
        $("#error_lawfirm_name").html("");
    }
    if(!$("#lawfirm_name").val() == "") 
    {
        if(!NotNumeric($("#lawfirm_name").val()))
        {
            $("#error_lawfirm_name").html("Please Enter only character.");
            if(!alreadyFocussed){
                $('#lawfirm_name').focus();
                alreadyFocussed = true;
            }
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#error_lawfirm_name").html("");
        }
    }
    if(!$("#lawfirm_name").val() == "")
    {
        var iChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?";

         for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("lawfirm_name").value.length; i++)
         {
                if (iChars.indexOf(document.getElementById("lawfirm_name").value.charAt(i)) != -1) 
                {
                    $("#error_lawfirm_name").html("Your name has special characters. \nThese are not allowed.\n Please remove them and try again.");
                    if(!alreadyFocussed){
                        $('#lawfirm_name').focus();
                        alreadyFocussed = true;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    //$("#error_lawfirm_name").html("");
                }
          }

    }
    }
    if(first_name=='')
    {
        $("#error_first_name").html('Please enter First Name!');

        if(!alreadyFocussed){
            $('#first_name').focus();
            alreadyFocussed = true;
        }
        count++;
    }else{
        $("#error_first_name").html("");
    }
    if(!$("#first_name").val() == "") 
    {
        if(!NotNumeric($("#first_name").val()))
        {
            $("#error_first_name").html("Please Enter only character.");
            if(!alreadyFocussed){
                $('#first_name').focus();
                alreadyFocussed = true;
            }
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#error_first_name").html("");
        }
    }
    if(!$("#first_name").val() == "")
    {
        var iChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?";

         for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("first_name").value.length; i++)
         {
                if (iChars.indexOf(document.getElementById("first_name").value.charAt(i)) != -1) 
                {
                    $("#error_first_name").html("Your name has special characters. \nThese are not allowed.\n Please remove them and try again.");
                    if(!alreadyFocussed){
                        $('#first_name').focus();
                        alreadyFocussed = true;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    //$("#error_first_name").html("");
                }
          }

    }
    if(last_name=='')
    {
        $("#error_last_name").html('Please enter last Name!');

        if(!alreadyFocussed){
                        $('#last_name').focus();
                        alreadyFocussed = true;
                    }
                    count++;
    }else{
        $("#error_last_name").html("");
    }
    if(!$("#last_name").val() == "") 
    {
        if(!NotNumeric($("#last_name").val()))
        {
            $("#error_last_name").html("Please Enter only character.");
            if(!alreadyFocussed){
                        $('#last_name').focus();
                        alreadyFocussed = true;
                    }
                    count++;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#error_last_name").html("");
        }
    }
    if(!$("#last_name").val() == "")
    {
        var iChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?";

         for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("last_name").value.length; i++)
         {
                if (iChars.indexOf(document.getElementById("last_name").value.charAt(i)) != -1) 
                {
                    $("#error_last_name").html("Your name has special characters. \nThese are not allowed.\n Please remove them and try again.");
                    if(!alreadyFocussed){
                        $('#last_name').focus();
                        alreadyFocussed = true;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    //$("#error_last_name").html("");
                }
          }

    }

    if(mobile_no=='')
    {
        $("#error_mobile_no").html('Please enter mobile number!');

        if(!alreadyFocussed){
                        $('#mobile_no').focus();
                        alreadyFocussed = true;
                    }
                    count++;
    }else{
        $("#error_mobile_no").html("");
    }
    if(mobile_no!='')
    {    
        if(mobile_no.length < 10)
        {
            $("#error_mobile_no").html('Please enter 10 digit mobile number!');
            if(!alreadyFocussed){
                        $('#mobile_no').focus();
                        alreadyFocussed = true;
                    }
                    count++;
        }else{
            $("#error_mobile_no").html("");
        }
    }

    if(email_id=='')
    {
        $("#error_email").html('Please enter email!');

        if(!alreadyFocussed){
                        $('#email_id').focus();
                        alreadyFocussed = true;
                    }
                    count++;
    }else {
        $("#error_email").html("");
    }
    if(email_id!=''){
        if(!regEmail.test(email_id)){
            $("#error_email").html('Please enter a valid email.');
            if(!alreadyFocussed){
                        $('#email_id').focus();
                        alreadyFocussed = true;
                    }
                    count++;
            }else {
                $("#error_email").html('');
            }   
    }


    if(selection[0].checked == true)
    {

    if(practice_area=='')
    {
        $("#error_practice_area").html('Please enter area of practice!');
        if(!alreadyFocussed){
                        $('#practice_area').focus();
                        alreadyFocussed = true;
                    }
                    count++;
    }else {
        $("#error_practice_area").html('');
    }
    }
    else {
        $("#error_practice_area").html('');
    }
    if($("#country").val()=='')
    {
        $("#error_country").html('Please select country!');

        if(!alreadyFocussed){
                        $('#country').focus();
                        alreadyFocussed = true;
                    }
                    count++;
    }else {
        $("#error_country").hide();
    }

    if($("#state").val()=='')
    {
        $("#error_state").html('Please enter town!');

        if(!alreadyFocussed){
                        $('#state').focus();
                        alreadyFocussed = true;
                    }
                    count++;
    }else {
        $("#error_state").hide();
    }
    if(!$("#state").val() == "") 
    {
        if(Numeric($("#state").val()))
        {
            $("#error_state").html("Please Enter only character.");
            if(!alreadyFocussed){
                        $('#state').focus();
                        alreadyFocussed = true;
                    }
                    count++;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#error_state").html("");
        }
    }
    if($("#district").val()=='')
    {
        $("#error_district").html('Please enter city!');

        if(!alreadyFocussed){
                        $('#district').focus();
                        alreadyFocussed = true;
                    }
                    count++;
    }else {
        $("#error_district").hide();
    }
    if(!$("#district").val() == "") 
    {
        if(Numeric($("#district").val()))
        {
            $("#error_district").html("Please Enter only character.");
            if(!alreadyFocussed){
                        $('#district').focus();
                        alreadyFocussed = true;
                    }
                    count++;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#error_district").html("");
        }
    }
    if($("#pincode").val()=='')
    {
        $("#error_pincode").html('Please enter pincode!');

        if(!alreadyFocussed){
                        $('#pincode').focus();
                        alreadyFocussed = true;
                    }
                    count++;
    }else {
        $("#error_pincode").hide();
    }
    /*if(cvalue=='')
    {
        document.getElementById('error_authentication').innerHTML='Please enter security code!';

        if(!alreadyFocussed){
                        document.getElementById('authentication').focus();
                        alreadyFocussed = true;
                    }
                    count++;
    }
    else{
            document.getElementById('error_authentication').innerHTML="";
        }
    if(cvalue!='')
    {
        var securitycode = document.getElementById('scode').value;
        if(securitycode==0)
        {
            document.getElementById('error_authentication').innerHTML='Please enter correct security code!';
            if(!alreadyFocussed){
                        document.getElementById('authentication').focus();
                        alreadyFocussed = true;
                    }
                    count++;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('error_authentication').innerHTML="";
        }
    }*/

    if(count == 0){
    $('#myfrm').submit();
        if(cvalue!='')
            {
                document.getElementById('error_authentication').innerHTML="";
                $.post("<?php echo APP_ROOT_URL; ?>checkcode.php", { val: cvalue }, function(data) { 

                    if(data == "0") 
                    { 
                        document.getElementById('error_authentication').innerHTML='Please enter correct security code!';
                        if(!alreadyFocussed){
                            document.getElementById('authentication').focus();
                            alreadyFocussed = true;
                        }
                        sleep(10);
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#error_authentication").text('');


                    }
                });
                //return false;
                alert(document.getElementById('error_authentication').innerHTML);
                if(document.getElementById('error_authentication').innerHTML == '') { alert('testing true'); document.getElementById('myfrm').submit(); } else { alert('testing false'); return false; }
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById('error_authentication').innerHTML='Please enter security code!';
                if(!alreadyFocussed){
                    document.getElementById('authentication').focus();
                    alreadyFocussed = true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        //return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
});
});

function checkcode(valuecode)
 {
    var  dataString = 'val='+valuecode;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?php echo APP_ROOT_URL; ?>checkcode.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(value1)
            {
                document.getElementById('scode').value=value1;
                if(value1=='0')
                {
                    //alert('Please enter correct security code!');
                    document.getElementById('error`enter code here`_authentication').innerHTML='Please enter correct security code!';
                    document.getElementById('authentication').focus();
                    return false;               
                }else{
                        document.getElementById('error_authentication').innerHTML="";
                     }
            }
        });
```

html part

```
<form name="myfrm" id="myfrm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="button" id="mynewid" name="submit" value="Submit" class="sumbitbtn" /></div>
</form>
```

Please check and help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: without seeing your code is not possible to direct you in right direction.  Post your code here or fiddle it.

Comment: actually my code is too big so i am posting it in parts

Comment: wow, goto jsfiddle.net and make a fiddle instead. blockcode in comments isn't helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following steps to debug:

- sleep(10) is a syntax error in JavaScript; `setTimeout(function(){},1000)` is more like it
- Use [FireQuery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firequery/) to debug jQuery
- Use [EventBug](https://github.com/firebug/eventbug) to debug event handlers
- Use [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/) to debug AJAX requests